# Is there a Windows program to search for files that has these 4 specific features?

Tags: windows, file-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the fastest desktop search tools you’ve used on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8654/whats-the-fastest-desktop-search-tools-youve-used-on-windows)

Is there a Windows program to efficiently search for files that does not wear down the disks?

**Minimum** functional requirements:

- Search for names of files and folders
- Search with modification date, before/after. Ideally in a range.
- Search with file size, smaller/larger. Ideally in a range.
- Manual control of file/folder indexing

By *efficient* I mean it keeps a list of all files and folders (file/folder name, size, modification date, creation date) without the need to scan the disks for every search. And by not *wearing down* the disks I mean it should ***not*** try to keep the list of files updated. 
I am fine with doing this manually. I don't want constant disk activity on my system.

I have a lot files of my system and I am looking for a tool to efficiently search for files.
I am currently using [FreeCommander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeCommander)'s search facility. It is very powerful and much better than Windows XP's. But it does not cache anything.

I want ***complete manual control*** over when the list of files is updated and do not want to use the built-in search Windows.

Platform: Windows XP Professional x64 bit Edition.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/100502/please-suggest-a-file-search-tool-for-windows-that-is-not-google-desktop-and-doe and http://superuser.com/questions/8654/whats-the-fastest-desktop-search-tools-youve-used-on-windows

Comment: I would like to have reopened this question. I have 4 very specific requirements, I am not looking for a list of alternatives to Windows' search.

Answer (score 5):

### [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/)

It's by far the most efficient search tool I know

You couldn't stop the database auto-update actually (it will be implemented), but it's blazing fast because it use the NTFS USN journal... And there's a special version of the tool with update disabled [there](http://forum.voidtools.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=319)

(Personally I launch it at startup, and let it monitor changes, it's lightweight enough...)

[image]

#### Pros:

```
Quick file indexing
Locate files and folders by name instantly.
Clean and simple user interface
Small installation file
Minimal resource usage
Share files with others easily
Real-time updating
More...
```

#### Cons:

```
Works only with NTFS drive 
Need administrative privileges, so need to deal with uac...
Doesn't search content
```

Comment: Thanks. I have read through the FAQ now. Indexing can be controlled by simply quitting Everything. But can it use modification date and file size in the search?

Comment: Yes it can. Incredible tool that it is.

Comment: @outsideblasts, @fluxtendu: can you give a hint on how to use modification date and file size in the search? I have downloaded and run Everything, but can't find the place to set these options.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to search by filesize. But for changed files look at this post: http://forum.voidtools.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=606&p=1790&hilit=cm+cd+cw#p1790 (and maybe you will need a beta or alpha version)

Answer (score 0):

I use to use [agent ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/). Ugly as a Win95 program, but low on RAM and damn efficient !

Comment: The first search through my 2.5 million files with Agent Ransack took 52 minutes. I think it is significantly slower than with FreeCommander, but I have to confirm it. I searched for files larger than 300 MB that were modified after 2009-07-10 (73 matches).

Comment: The duration of subsequent searches was about 1 minute. But I think this was caused by caching by the RAM rich 64 bit version of Windows I tested it on. After a restart of the computer the search time was back to about 50 minutes.

Comment: @Riduidel: is there some setting I can change to make it more efficient? I used the 2010 Beta version, 64 bit version.

Comment: Well, I don't know, I must confess I never use it on such huge volumes.